# Process usage for the past X days?

Tags: process

Let's say I have a process running for 3 months without stop. I want to see some statistics how this process has behaved? What can I do in order to track this?

Comment: Did you have a look at [rrdtool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/)? There are a lot of examples around for performance and process monitoring as well as other software built upon rrdtool; see e.g. [eLuna](http://www.eluna.org/eluna_graph_system.html), which is written in perl and may be modified easily.

Comment: Or look at `man pidstat`, which shows some process statistics.